# How to submit a form that uses more than one Spinner in Android App?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

I am new to Java and Android. Here is my problem

I have two Spinners that have distinct ids, BUT same options like, Yes, No, Maybe , Dont Know.

The spinners are provided to select answer to two different questions. So obviously they will have two different ids.

I have already created String array that stores these Yes, No, Maybe , and Dont Know, .

So lets say the user wants to submit these answers then he clicks on a button ,

I have used android:onclick="mysubmit"  in XML

questions in STRING.XML that need to be answered using SPINNERS

---

```
<string name="question_first">Do you Cough ?</string>
<string name="question_second">Do yo have phlegm in your chest?</string>
<string name="patient_feedback_button">Send Feedback</string>


<string name="feedbacktype"/>
<string name="feedbacktype1">Yes</string>
<string name="feedbacktype2">No</string>
<string name="feedbacktype3">Maybe</string>  
<string name="feedbacktype4">DONT KNOW</string>
<string-array name="feedbacktypelist">
<item>@string/feedbacktype1</item>
<item>@string/feedbacktype2</item>
<item>@string/feedbacktype3</item>
<item>@string/feedbacktype4</item>
</string-array>
```

---

Spinners in activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/feedbacktype"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist">
  </Spinner>





<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType1"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:prompt="@string/feedbacktype"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist">
</Spinner>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback_asthma"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/patient_feedback_button"
    android:onClick="mysubmit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </Button>
```

My GOAL :
when I click on Button which has name or title as Send Feedback, it should call , mysubmit in Java.

And then it should bring me a form that will help to submit this STRING options that I read from Spinner.

In Java, I have

```
public void mysubmit(View button) {
    // Handles data from spinner
 final Spinner feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);
    String feedbackType = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

final Spinner feedbackSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType1);
      String feedbackType1 = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
 }
```

I will appreciate your help as I am learning Android and Java.

Thanks,
jay

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Are you not getting selected item value from spinner?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, I am not sure how to read the input from 2 spinners.

Comment: did you solve this? how did you do that?